# lighttpd: mod_rewrite ignoring rules in .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am about to learn rewrite rules on lighttpd. 
I have a question: is this the normal state of the art that lighttpd is ignoring the .htaccess files ?

I have some rules in .htaccess and they where ignored, when I write them to the lighttpd.conf they are executed correctly.

how can I enable mod rewrite to read the .htaccess files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [Lighttpd FAQ](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Do-you-support-htaccess-files):

> **Do you support .htaccess files?**
>
> No. *Lighty*'s design does not permit implementing this functionality as config files are loaded at startup time and `.htaccess` would be needed to be parsed at request time.
>
> […]
>
> Furthermore, `.htaccess` files are *Apache* config files. We would need to write a parser and it might not even be possible to map all functionality to *lighty* logic.